# relativelayout not rendering correctly

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make an chat with 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView per Tabelrow.I am using a relativeLayout to arrange them, but when I run the app everything is placed in top right corner on top of each other... I have googled my way through the internet but i couldn't find anything to help me. Can anyone please help?? maybe give me some directions??

```
        TableRow trr = new TableRow(this);
        trr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
        tl.addView(trr);

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams trrllp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10);
        trrllp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
        rl.setLayoutParams(trrllp);
        trr.addView(rl);

        ImageView ivSvart = new ImageView(this);

        TextView tvchat = new TextView(this);
        tvchat.setText(ChatH.get(i)[2]);

        String s = ChatH.get(i)[1];
        Long l = Long.valueOf(s);
        time = new Date(l*1000);

        TextView tvTimeDate = new TextView(this);
        tvTimeDate.setText(time + ", " + navn);


        if(b_ID.equals(MinID)){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rltvlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-70, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rltvlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rltvlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rltvlp.setMargins(0, 5, 100, 0);
            tvchat.setLayoutParams(rltvlp);
            tvchat.setTextColor(0xFFFEFEFE);
            tvchat.setTextSize(18);
            rl.addView(tvchat);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlivlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80);
            rlivlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, tvTimeDate.getId());
            rlivlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rlivlp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 10);
            ivSvart.setLayoutParams(rlivlp);
            rl.addView(ivSvart);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rltvlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rltvlp2.setMargins(0, 5, 15, 0);
            rltvlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvchat.getId());
            rltvlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, ivSvart.getId());
            tvTimeDate.setLayoutParams(rltvlp2);
            rl.addView(tvTimeDate);

        }
```

I have tried in multiple ways, but have not succeeded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure that Your Parent Layout is Relative Layout in which you are programmatic ally Creating child Relative Layouts. This will work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it didn't work for me. Do the main parent have to be relative or just the parent of the TabelLayout?